# implement map globe Rajawali into fragment Android

Tags: android, fragment, rajawali

I have problems with incorporating the world map on a fragment android
Since an activity is performed in this way :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final RajawaliSurfaceView surface = new RajawaliSurfaceView(this);
    surface.setFrameRate(60.0);
    surface.setRenderMode(IRajawaliSurface.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);

    // Add mSurface to your root view
    addContentView(surface, new  ActionB

ar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    renderer = new Renderer(this);
    surface.setSurfaceRenderer(renderer);
}
```

But when I want to do it in a fragment gives me error line

```
addContentView(surface, new  ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final RajawaliSurfaceView surface = new RajawaliSurfaceView(getActivity());
        surface.setFrameRate(60.0);
        surface.setRenderMode(IRajawaliSurface.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);

        // Add mSurface to your root view
        addContentView(surface, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        renderer = new Renderer(getActivity());
        surface.setSurfaceRenderer(renderer);
    }
```

Comment: Mauricio! very always try to post the error message displayed in logCat!

Comment: Error:(81, 9) error: cannot find symbol method addContentView(RajawaliSurfaceView,LayoutParams)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error messages. The error that you are having is that `addContentView` is **outside a method** (and so it cannot be resolved to a symbol).

Answer (score 4):

Well i think you are misunderstanding the difference between a Fragment and Activity, this error message:

> cannot find symbol method addContentView()

points that this method doesn´t exist!

This is a very basic example of **how to load the Rajawali3D map into fragment Android**.

[image]

Create the Activity, adding the Fragment transaction, the fragment is loaded into the `map_fragment` container, defined in `act_frag_map` layout:

```
public class Map3DFragActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RajawaliSurfaceView rajawaliTexture;
    Renderer renderer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_frag_map);

        setFragment();

    }

    protected void setFragment() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment mapFragment = new FragmentMap();
        FragmentTransaction ft =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.map_fragment, mapFragment).commit();
    }

}
```

This is the layout containing a fragment, adding in the property `android:name` the name of our class fragment:

**act_frag_map**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentExampleActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:name="com.test.FragmentMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Fragment that creates the map!

**FragmentMap**

```
import org.rajawali3d.surface.RajawaliSurfaceView;

public class FragmentMap extends Fragment {

    public RajawaliSurfaceView rajawaliTexture;
    Renderer renderer;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag_map,
                container, false);

        rajawaliTexture = (RajawaliSurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.rajawali_surface);
        renderer = new Renderer(getActivity());
        rajawaliTexture.setSurfaceRenderer(renderer);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // make sure this line exists

    }
}
```

**activity_frag_map**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:surfaceview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <org.rajawali3d.surface.RajawaliSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/rajawali_surface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        surfaceview:frameRate="60.0"
        surfaceview:renderMode="RENDER_WHEN_DIRTY"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks But I still have problems , now is activity_frag_map , rendering Problems

 

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.onResume(GLSurfaceView.java:562)

you have the code from this example? We appreciate it if I can I send my gmail .
mf.reyessn@gmail.com


Thank you